# Are 120V Feed Hot Wires in a panel/sub-panel Interchangeable?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I am feeding a sub-panel using four separate conductors (2 hots, neutral and ground) from the main panel. Intuition tells me that there is no difference between the two hot wires. As in either of these two cables can go in any of the two hot lugs on the sub-panel. Just wanted to verify that that's indeed the case.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit further by "kept separate"? Obviously the hots will originate from a 125AMP breaker and will end up on two separate hot lugs in the sub-panel. My question is mainly whether each needs to be identified as unique from the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. There is no functional difference between the hots. They can even be the same color. Typical colors are:

- Hots - Black and black or black and red
- Neutral - White
- Ground - Green

Above 4 AWG, you can use black for everything with the neutral and ground marked white and green on each end. With any smaller size, neutral must be white or gray and ground must be green. Hot (with certain exceptions in *cables*) must be any color *except* white, gray or green.

Comment: Thank you. I am using 2/0 Aluminum for the hots and neutral and a 6AWG bare copper for the ground. So I think I will only need to mark the neutral with white tape.

Comment: Correct. Bare ground is (in most cases) perfectly fine. But neutral has to be clearly marked.

Answer (score 0):

If it is three phase system, phase sequence is only matter then you connect 3-phase electrical motor. Otherwise it is not important. Just do not mix with neutral. If by 4 wires you mean ground as forth wire( which is unusual), two hot are equal.

Comment: This is residential in United States - so single phase.

Comment: Only in North America. You can not be sure about the rest of world.

Comment: And In NA the ground usually not count, 4-wires means 4 wires + ground.

Comment: 4 wires in a typical NM cable, a.k.a. "/4", means 4 + ground. But when we are talking about feeds to panels, typically 3 means no ground, 4 means yes ground.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2 Codidact It is more complicated and word "typically" does not cover all the cases. I.e. in Canada if your using EMT conduit with screw type connectors and couplings the ground wire not necessarily. If any type of cable used, the ground is not count.  OP already edited the question but my answer was made before the edit.